# How to implement @Auditable with dropwizard

Tags: java, hibernate, dropwizard, hibernate-envers

I want to implement @Auditable with Dropwizard. Which will create the *_audit table and also store the details with Revinfo table?

I am using Dropwizard with Liquibase.

I have added @Auditable on Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "user_plan")
@Audited
public class UserPlan extends IdentityEntity
```

And try to update the table throwing the error

```
 ! java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.envers.internal.synchronization.AuditProcessManager$2.doAfterTransactionCompletion(ZLorg/hibernate/engine/spi/SharedSessionContractImplementor;)V
! at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue$AfterTransactionCompletionProcessQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:975)
! at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.afterTransactionCompletion(ActionQueue.java:509)
! at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2472)
! at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.afterTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:479)
! at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.afterCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:176)
! at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$200(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:38)
! at org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.rollback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:252)
! at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.rollback(TransactionImpl.java:100)
! at io.dropwizard.hibernate.UnitOfWorkAspect.rollbackTransaction(UnitOfWorkAspect.java:144)
! at io.dropwizard.hibernate.UnitOfWorkAspect.onError(UnitOfWorkAspect.java:106)
! at io.dropwizard.hibernate.UnitOfWorkApplicationListener$UnitOfWorkEventListener.onEvent(UnitOfWorkApplicationListener.java:85)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.monitoring.CompositeRequestEventListener.onEvent(CompositeRequestEventListener.java:71)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.internal.process.RequestProcessingContext.triggerEvent(RequestProcessingContext.java:226)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$Responder.process(ServerRuntime.java:472)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime$2.run(ServerRuntime.java:334)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:271)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors$1.call(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:267)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:317)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime.process(ServerRuntime.java:305)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.handle(ApplicationHandler.java:1154)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.serviceImpl(WebComponent.java:473)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:427)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:388)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:341)
! at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:228)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.NonblockingServletHolder.handle(NonblockingServletHolder.java:49)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1623)
! at io.dropwizard.servlets.ThreadNameFilter.doFilter(ThreadNameFilter.java:35)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.handle(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:45)
! at io.dropwizard.jersey.filter.AllowedMethodsFilter.doFilter(AllowedMethodsFilter.java:39)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.ManagedFilterPipeline.dispatch(ManagedFilterPipeline.java:121)
! at com.google.inject.servlet.GuiceFilter.doFilter(GuiceFilter.java:133)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1610)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:540)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextHandle(ScopedHandler.java:255)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1345)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:203)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:480)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.nextScope(ScopedHandler.java:201)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1247)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:144)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
! at com.codahale.metrics.jetty9.InstrumentedHandler.handle(InstrumentedHandler.java:239)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.RoutingHandler.handle(RoutingHandler.java:52)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.gzip.GzipHandler.handle(GzipHandler.java:703)
! at io.dropwizard.jetty.BiDiGzipHandler.handle(BiDiGzipHandler.java:67)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.RequestLogHandler.handle(RequestLogHandler.java:56)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.StatisticsHandler.handle(StatisticsHandler.java:174)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:132)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:502)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)
! at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
! at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Added dependency

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-envers</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I am expecting that once I start the server, it will automatically create an _audit table and respected rev info table.

Comment: is it hibernate-core and hibernate-envers same version?